# What does the error code 502 prompted by Galaxybase's 51314 port mean?

Tags: graph-databases

I'm facing a problem when attempting to access port 51314 with Galaxybase graph database. The response I receive is an HTTP ERROR 502.

I have confirmed that the issue is specifically related to accessing port 51314.
Other ports and services on the same machine are functioning properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP ERROR 502 typically indicates a connection timeout. To investigate and ensure the deployment of services is functioning correctly, you can follow these steps:

Execute the command `docker ps` on the Galaxybase machine to check if the admin container is present.

1. If the previous step confirms the existence of the admin container, execute `curl localhost:51314/index.html` to verify if it returns webpage information.
2. If you are unable to access the webpage information, it might indicate a misconfiguration of services or network settings. Review relevant configuration files and network settings.
3. If the issue persists, attempt to restart the Galaxybase service and try accessing port 51314 again.
4. If the problem still persists, provide more detailed logs or error messages to help us better understand the source of the issue and offer more accurate solutions.